# How to require not empty on one field if another specific field is not empty with FormValidation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, formvalidation-plugin

I am working on reset password form with JavaScript FormValidation library where I want to require current password field if new password field has value or if current password has value then to require new password field.

Here is some code that I tried:

```
FormValidation.formValidation(
    KTUtil.getById('myForm'),
    {
        fields: {
            cpassword: {
                validators: {
                    remote: {
                        message: 'Password does not matched !',
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: base_url + "controller/current_password",
                        data: {user_id: $('#myForm').find('input[name="id"]').val()}
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'You must enter at least one contact method',
                        callback: function (g) {
                           return !KTUtil.getById('myForm').querySelector('[name="npassword"]').is(':empty');

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            npassword: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'You must enter at least one contact method',
                        callback: function (g) {
                           return !KTUtil.getById('myForm').querySelector('[name="cpassword"]').is(':empty');

                        }
                    },
                    identical: {
                        compare: function () {
                            return KTUtil.getById('myForm').querySelector('[name="nvpassword"]').value;
                        },
                        message: 'The password and  confirm password are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
            nvpassword: {
                validators: {
                    identical: {
                        compare: function () {
                            return KTUtil.getById('myForm').querySelector('[name="npassword"]').value;
                        },
                        message: 'The password and  confirm password are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        plugins: {
            trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
            bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap({
                eleInvalidClass: '',
                eleValidClass: '',
            }),
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Comment: cpassword always showing empty or required  error but i want if nvpassword is  not empty then show the error same in nvpassword field too.. i hope u get it .